# Fractional-Differential-Equation tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Fractional Differential Equations are becoming very important. I propose to the community to consider it a tag, and also its abbreviation FDE.

To give a flavor of its importance I'm including an article in which the Covid pandemic was studied with FDE: [Application of piecewise fractional differential equation to COVID-19 infection dynamics - 2022 - Xiao-Ping Li et.al.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35694036/)

Comment: Thanks for asking before just creating the tag.  The maturity of Math.SE means that most tag ideas have been tried, and the Close As Duplicate notice points to a canonical thread for managing tags.  In your particular case there is the existing tag [fractional calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractional-calculus) that might serve the purpose sufficiently.

Comment: @hardmath, according to your explanation, the tags ordinary-differential equation, and partial-differential-equation should be covered by the tag calculus, and do not need to exist. But they exist nevertheless; why? Because some calculus questions do not deal  with differential equations. Second, you may notice that in my question "Fractional Bernoulli equation and logistic function", I was forced to add the incorrect tag ordinary-differential-equation, to explain that the question deals with differential equations; but it is misleading.

Comment: My Comment was intended to inform on tag management, not to argue the merits of the "tags ordinary differential equation [and] partial differential equation."  Tags are important for search and automatic identification of related posts.  They do not replace your need "to explain that the question deals with differential equations" in the body of the post.

Comment: @hardmath, I posted the request in the tag thread; it was upvoted three times. Some tag maintenance instruction suggest to create it (for which I do not have enough privilege), and if I do not have the privilege yet, to ask ask the community to create it. I've done that , both here and in the tag thread, but nothing is happening. What else can I do to make it happen?

Comment: I've made a case for you in the tagging chatroom.  I'll follow up in the canonical tag as above.